# Difference between ctrl+g and ctrl+f

Tags: google-chrome

How <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> is different from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> in Chrome?

I could not find any difference between these two keyboard shortcuts in `google-chrome`, both opens the same boxes. Isn't there any difference?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> actually don't do the same thing in Chrome.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> simply brings up the search menu. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> (and continuing to press it) will cycle through all of the different selections that are highlighted.

<kbd>F3</kbd> behaves similarly to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will cycle backwards through the highlights.

Comment: Hitting `Enter` while having opened the search menu with `Ctrl+F` also cycles through the highlighted occurrences. As far as I can tell, it's the exact same search menu you get, there are just different ways of getting to it and interacting with it. In that sense, they all do the same thing: bring up the search menu.

Comment: After `Ctrl`+`f`, pressing `Shift`+`Enter` also cycles backwards through the highlights.